# how can display another array list element in text view with selected item in spinner that populated with same array list

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner

hi im android programmer and i want to display my price of product in text view when i selected item in spinner

so , i create array list and convert my json object to array list with product class and adapt my array in spinner with fundapter

so my spinner get data and inflated on any view has been created in parent

so i wana , select my product name which name is ("نام محصول") and then this object load data from my array list so i wana take price of any product i selected in spinner to display it in text view which has value "0"

please help me to take position of this array list which represent data in my spinner and show my price in text view .  please see my app pic and code

[app view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVsAo.jpg)

---

so here my json file pic

[json pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Gaz.jpg)

```
public  void add (View v){
```

count=count+1;
        LayoutInflater in = getLayoutInflater();

```
    final LinearLayout line = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentorder);

    final View view=in.inflate(R.layout.packet_list
            , line , false);

    TextView txt=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    txt.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    TextView co =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cotxt);
    co.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(OrderActivity.this, new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String s) {
                Log.d(ORD ,s);
                product = new JsonConverter<products>().toArrayList(s, products.class);

                BindDictionary<products> dict = new BindDictionary<products>();
                dict.addStringField(R.id.txtitem, new StringExtractor<products>() {
                    @Override
                    public String getStringValue(products product, int position) {
                        return "" + product.nameproduct ;
                    }
                });

                BindDictionary<products> dict1 = new BindDictionary<products>();
                dict1.addStringField(R.id.txtcategory, new StringExtractor<products>() {
                    @Override
                    public String getStringValue(products product, int position) {
                        return "" + product.category ;
                    }
                });
                adapter = new FunDapter<>(OrderActivity.this , product ,R.layout.spinner_list ,dict);
                lvproduct = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                lvproduct.setAdapter(adapter);
                FunDapter<products> adapter1 = new FunDapter<>(OrderActivity.this , product ,R.layout.category_list ,dict1);
                category = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
                category.setAdapter(adapter1);


                line.addView(view);
                lvproduct.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        task1.execute("http://mybofeh.ir/android/listback");


}
```

and here my product class

public class products {
@SerializedName("idproduct")

public  int idproduct ;

@SerializedName("name product")

public String name product;

@SerializedName("category")

```
public String category;

@SerializedName("price")
```

public BigInteger price;

}